# Pushing std::count result into vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create std::map with "T,int"  but manually. I've copied std::set of data into clear vector, because I want to have an access to elements of unique elements. Here is a following code.

```
    template<typename T>
void foo<T>::function()
{
    std::set<T> unique_set(A.begin(), A.end());
    std::copy(unique_set.begin(), unique_set.end(), std::inserter(vector_uniq, vector_uniq.begin()));
    for (const auto&elem : vector_uniq)
    {
        counter = std::count(A.begin(), A.end(), elem); // declared in header as unsigned int
    }
}
```

Is it possible to push value of counter to another vector ? Then I would have two vectors of value and their occurences and those two vectors will be used in another function.  That's why I would like to have separated containers. Thank's for all responses.

Comment: Don't use `std::inserter` with `vector`. It exhibits undefined behavior, as the very first `insert` invalidates the iterator.

Comment: What's the supposed role of `unique_set` in this code? You populate it, but then don't use it for anything.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so how can I copy set container ?

Comment: Copy what to what else? Your code is very difficult to make sense of, because it uses variables that were never declared, and so their type can only be guessed at.

Comment: My mistake, I've edited copy A Vector to set Vector

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Yes, I tried something lime this : ( on the same loop ) @0x499602D2 empty_vector.push_back(counter ) but its doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it doesn't work". You need to provide more detail.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I tried to debug this line and It doesn't stop. And when I tried to print out result in loop for(const auto & item : empty_vector) { cout << item;  } incremental linker stops procces. With C1001 error code after.

Comment: `vector_uniq.assign(unique_set.begin(), unique_set.end());` . Not clear why you want to copy a set to a vector though - you can iterate directly over `unique_set` just as well.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik I want to copy elem of set to Vector because i cannot iterate through set on another function

Comment: What's stopping you, exactly?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik vector is copied correctly. But adding counter like empty_vector(counter) is working but printing with auto loop or iterating through this vector makes problem.

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. My crystal ball is cloudy lately.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your second vector for the count results:

```
for (const auto&elem : vector_uniq) {
    auto counter = std::count(A.begin(), A.end(), elem); // declared in header as unsigned int
    vector_count.push_back(counter);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've add it. Thank you a lot :> But now How can I iterate trough second vector of numbers  ?  Because, if I use for ( auto& i:vector_count){ std::cout << i <<"\n"; } then my compilator said " Microsoft Incremental Linker stop his work"

Comment: Without seeing more of the declaration of the `foo` type/class/struct, it's hard to guess the cause. But seems like a linker problem and not a compile problem as seen from your quote.